# How do you serve your HTML on the browser?

Tags: windows, browser, cmd

I'm a web developer I recently got my computer wiped last week and now I'm downloading everything that I used to have. I'm starting a new project and I was trying to serve locally on the chrome browser with:

```
static .
```

but that command doesn't work for me anymore in the command prompt.

so I have to do this command:

```
start {file address}
```

so if I wanted to serve my HTML template I'd have to do this

```
start C:\dev\React-Basics\src\index.html
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this so I can use static . ?

Comment: As far as I am aware, `static` is not a standard Windows command; you need to install something that provides that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound as if you had a simple node package to serve your files, perhaps [node-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static) or something else.

Comment: wow, you are right. thanks man. instead of node-static i'll use reload. reload is just like node-static but it reloads the browser when you save your file.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Remember to accept this as the answer :) @Kevorkian